Build WordPress package too large
I am attempting to create a build for a WordPress plugin, and within my package.json
I have
"scripts": {
    "watch": "clear && webpack --watch --mode development",
    "compile": "clear && webpack --progress --mode production",
    "translate": "wp i18n make-pot ./ languages/plugin-test.pot --exclude=builds/,node_modules/,src,builds --ignore-domain --allow-root --skip-packages",
    "build": "clear && grunt preBuildClean && npm run compile && npm run translate && grunt build:pro && grunt finish"
},

This will successfully build a package, but the size of the build/plugin-test-1.0.0.zip is approximately 78MB, which is excessively large. This is because vendor/ directory is included, which contains a collection of Composer packages necessary to run PHP functionality.
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt)

    const files = [
        'assets/**',
        'app/**',
        'core/**',
        'languages/**',
        'uninstall.php',
        'wpmudev-plugin-test.php',
        'vendor/**',
        '!**/*.map',
    ]

    const excludeCopy = files
        .slice(0)
        .concat([
            'changelog.txt',
        ])

    const changelog = grunt.file.read('.changelog')

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // Clean temp folders and release copies.
        clean: {
            temp: {
                src: ['**/*.tmp', '**/.afpDeleted*', '**/.DS_Store'],
                dot: true,
                filter: 'isFile',
            },
            assets: ['assets/css/**', 'assets/js/**'],
            folder_v2: ['build/**'],
        },

        checktextdomain: {
            options: {
                text_domain: 'wpmudev-plugin-test',
                keywords: [
                    '__:1,2d',
                    '_e:1,2d',
                    '_x:1,2c,3d',
                    'esc_html__:1,2d',
                    'esc_html_e:1,2d',
                    'esc_html_x:1,2c,3d',
                    'esc_attr__:1,2d',
                    'esc_attr_e:1,2d',
                    'esc_attr_x:1,2c,3d',
                    '_ex:1,2c,3d',
                    '_n:1,2,4d',
                    '_nx:1,2,4c,5d',
                    '_n_noop:1,2,3d',
                    '_nx_noop:1,2,3c,4d',
                ],
            },
            files: {
                src: [
                    'app/templates/**/*.php',
                    'core/**/*.php',
                    '!core/external/**', // Exclude external libs.
                    'google-analytics-async.php',
                ],
                expand: true,
            },
        },

        copy: {
            pro: {
                src: excludeCopy,
                dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>/',
            },
        },

        compress: {
            pro: {
                options: {
                    mode: 'zip',
                    archive: './build/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.zip',
                },
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>/',
                src: ['**/*'],
                dest: '<%= pkg.name %>/',
            },
        },

    })

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-search')

    grunt.registerTask('version-compare', ['search'])
    grunt.registerTask('finish', function () {
        const json = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
        const file = './build/' + json.name + '-' + json.version + '.zip'
        grunt.log.writeln('Process finished.')
        grunt.log.writeln('----------')
    })

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'checktextdomain',
        'copy:pro',
        'compress:pro',
    ])

    grunt.registerTask('preBuildClean', [
        'clean:temp',
        'clean:assets',
        'clean:folder_v2',
    ])
}

I want to remove the vendor and replace it with composer.json like
const files = [
    ...,
    'composer.json',
    ...,
] 

because its possible to run composer install on remote server.
What is the impact?
What is the wordpress best practice for this?
